# c++: cin.clear() doesnt reset the stream

Tags: c++

My issue is that I cannot reset the `cin`'s stream if an error occurred. For example, if I input a string when an int is required, and if I then clear the stream, when looping to the next time, I still reach a `cin.fail()-if`.

Any help?

**My code is the following:**

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    while(cin>>i,!cin.eof())
    {
        if(cin.fail())
        {
            cin.clear();
            continue;
        }
        cout<<i<<endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

**Btw:** For information, I'm using Visual Studio as an IDE.

Comment: You don't need `!cin.eof()` in your loop expression, as the `>>` operator returns the stream and it can be used in boolean expressions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Except that here, he only wants to loop if the error is _not_ due to EOF.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the string is still there, since you haven't extracted it.  So the
next read will fail as well.  You need to use `cin.ignore` to skip over
the illegal characters.

Comment: Well, I guess i'm not using it right, since it doesnt work. Could you add it to my example code? I've tried adding it to the if, above and under cin.clear(), but to no avail.

Comment: Edit: Made it work by finding another thread. It works using:
    

`cin.clear(); 
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Answer (score 1):

Use something like:

```
int i;
while(cin>>i,!cin.eof())
{
    if(cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();
        string dummy;
        cin >> dummy;
        continue;
    }
    cout<<i<<endl;
}
```

This will skip over the next word.  If you entered something like `derp10 20` you'd get 20.